# Why is my washing machine so loud during the spin cycle?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a top loading washing machine. It is sitting on the bottom of a rack. The dryer is sitting on the top shelf of a rack. (The rack was made to stack these two units on top of each other).

During the spin cycle the washing machine is *really* loud. Is this typical? I've heard washing machines that has a similar sound but not the same volume!

What could be the issue with it, if there is one? How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

The washing machine is actually not physically sitting on the rack. It has wheels and is sitting on the floor. The rack structure is really to loft the dryer above the washer. I also checked to make sure that all wheels are touching the ground.

Comment: Does the washer rest on the floor or on the rack?  If on the rack does it sit on it's feet or on it's frame?  If it sits on it's feet on the ground then you probably need to balance the machine?  Also, can the washing machine make the rack vibrate?

Answer (score 2):

The spin cycle is normally the loudest part of the washing program. To compare the sound of your machine with others, you should consider whether it's designed to be extra quiet or not, and whether it has a high-speed spin cycle or not.

My washing machine has a 1200 RPM high speed spin cycle, but it's designed to be quiet so it's not very loud anyway. It also has the option to run the spin cycle at a slower speed, which makes it even more quiet.

You can buy rubber washers designed to be placed under the feet of the washing machine, which will reduce the vibrations in your rack.

Although the spin cycle is noisy, you should listen if there is a banging noise or if it's just loud. If there is a banging noise the clothes may be unevenly balanced (overload?), or there may be something wrong with the suspension so that it can't absorb the vibrations.

Comment: No banging noise, just really loud...sounds like ratatatatatatata...

Answer (score 1):

To balance a washing machine all you need is torpedo level and an adjustable wrench.  Each foot is adjustable with a lock nut.  Loosen the lock nut and make the leg longer or shorter then tighten the lock nut to keep it from vibrating and changing height.

With the torpedo level in the middle of the front check for level.  Repeat on the sides and then the back.  Now by tilting the machine adjust the feet to where you think they need to be.  Check again with level until you get it where it should be.  The floors are not level so not all will be the same.  If you end up with all the legs too high then just lower them equally and re-check until level.  Older machines might need persuasion, penetrating oil and/or channel locks.  Don't forget to loosen or tighten the lock nuts or all your work will be in vain.

This might not be the answer, but it won't hurt it being level.

Comment: the washer is actually on wheels. Do you think that is causing it to be loud?

Comment: Whether it is on wheels or pegs is not necessarily relevant (it could let it move side to side more than one on pegs) but it is important either way to get all 4 wheels on the ground otherwise it will rattle!

Comment: @milesmeow make sure all the wheels are on the ground.  Because floors are never level is why I suggested what I suggested.  I like to start out with the cheapest and simplest fixes first and work my way up.  There are other reasons for the machine to be noisey, like tub or motor bearings, bad belts, or like the Maytags I worked on the transmissions could wear out.

Answer (score 0):

I think its quite common, especially top loaders (the physics means its harder to dampen vibrations) and older washing machines.

New ones are very quiet (well mine is 1400rpm).

I had a very loud built-in washing machine once; just adding some folded up cardboard to where it hit against the kitchen unit reduced the noise substantially. Maybe you can do something similar.

Comment: I don't think my washer is necessarily hitting anything...I'll check.